# Play(Loop) Imacro from Excel VBA and put the Max Value in IMacro for playing Loop

Tags: excel, imacros, vba

```
Dim iim1, iret
Set iim1 = CreateObject("imacros")
iret = iim1.iiminit("-fx")
iret = iim1.iimplay("PayU_Refunds")
iret = iim1.iimDisplay("Done!")
iret = iim1.iimClose()
```

I want to use Play(Loop) instead of "iimplay" and also want to put the value in "MAX" box of imacro, from excel vba, is that possible; if yes, kindly suggest the code.

Comment: View an example of how to loop over a number [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimSet()).

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you can do is to make the loop directly in Excel, playing the iMacro several times: Change the variable `{{!LOOP}}` in your iMacro to `{{loop}}`and then use `iimSet("loop", i)` to set the value of the loop each time it is played.

It should be something like this:

```
Dim iim1, iret
Set iim1 = CreateObject("imacros")
For i = 1 To 5
    iret = iim1.iiminit("-fx")
    iret = iim1.iimSet("loop", i)
    iret = iim1.iimplay("PayU_Refunds")
Next i
iret = iim1.iimDisplay("Done!")
iret = iim1.iimClose()
```

Can't test it right now in Excel, but give it a try and let us know if worked :)